# How to connect QTableView selection changed Signal

Tags: c++, qt

I inserted a `QTableView` in my GUI and set `selectionMode = SingleSelection` , `selectionBehavior = SelectRows`.

I want to connect my slot to a signal (*selection changed* or another signal) by changing the selected row.

Please see my code:

```
connect(ui->tableView->selectionModel(),
    SIGNAL( selectionChanged(const QItemSelection&,
    const QItemSelection&)), this ,SLOT(myslot()));
```

I get an error message:

> QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::selectionChanged(const QItemSelection&, const QItemSelection&) to Info::myslot

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you mean by `"My Code doesn't work"`.  As an aside you should probably move to the [`Qt5` signal/slot syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's difficult to identify the real source of the problem but the message...

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::selectionChanged(const QItemSelection&, const QItemSelection&) to Info::myslot
```

suggests that the expression...

```
ui->tableView->selectionModel()
```

evaluates to a null pointer.  You need to ensure your UI has been set up *before* making the connection.

Comment: That error is typical when trying to use the selectionModel without setting a model in sight, that is, selectionModel is null until the view is set to a model in sight: so the solution should be: `ui->tableView->setModel(model);` `connect(ui->tableView->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged, this, &FooClass::myslot);`